# SMOTE for regression

Tags: r, sampling, smote, imbalanced-learn, smotenc

I am looking into upsampling an imbalanced dataset for a regression problem (Numerical target variables) in python.

I attached paper and R package that implement SMOTE for regression, can anyone recommend a similar package in Python? Otherwise, what other methods can be use to upsample the numerical target variable?

[SMOTE for Regression](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download;jsessionid=23D61BE14B6C14E9D33DE8CE287A3C4E?doi=10.1.1.432.7617&rep=rep1&type=pdf)

[smoteRegress: SMOTE algorithm for imbalanced regression problems](https://rdrr.io/cran/UBL/man/smoteRegress.html)

**Update:**

I found the following python library which implements Synthetic Minority Over-Sampling Technique for Regression with Gaussian Noise

[smogn](https://github.com/nickkunz/smogn)

Comment: the imblearn package implements the smote oversampling method

Comment: @VictorNg but it does not allow continuous target variable.

Comment: oh right regression. i need to learn to read. would you lose too much information by binning the continuous variable into categories?

Comment: Yes,  I will lose much because I am trying to optimize the MSE

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think SMOGN will work for your problem. The method is described in a paper titled: "SMOGN: a Pre-processing Approach for Imbalanced Regression". You can find it on arXiv. There is also a python implementation called "SMOGN" which can be installed through PyPI. You can find the package description at https://pypi.org/project/smogn/

Comment: Thanks! I found out about the same package a few weeks ago.